# Timer is sometimes enabled false when using Stop() and Start()?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a simple timer in .net 4.0, the interval is set to 1000 (= 1 second) and enabled = true. To start the timer I use `.Start()`. Everything works fine so far.

Then in the event of the timer I got this :

```
private void MyTimerEvent()
{
    myTimer.Stop();
    myTimer.Start();

    //Some other work is done not related to the timer
}
```

The problem is that as soon as the timer event have been runned once it will stop throwing the event and its seems like it is set to `enabled = false` even after the myTimer.Start(); sometimes. But I am not setting the `enabled = false` at all?

What am I doing wrong?

Edit : `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is the one I use.

Comment: Post more of your code. I believe you're mis-diagnosing the problem.

Comment: You know that the System.Windows.Forms.Timer is synced with UI thread (so if the UI thread "hangs" there is also no event fired by the timer... Are you shure no one else does call Stop()? I guess there must be some other problem within your code (+1 @CodesInChaos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `Stop` on a `Forms.Timer` it simply does an `Enabled=False`. Same with `Start`. If your Timer is `enabled` there is no need to call `Start` because the timer is running already.
You can check yourself with Reflector et al:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    public void Start()
    {
        this.Enabled = true;
    }

    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I solve this then? Should I use the Enabled instead of the start and stop?

Comment: At least you should stick to either Start/Stop or Enabled True/False. Which one doesn't make any difference - esp. since the JIT-compiler will most likely inline the Start/Stop methods anyway. Does not solve your initial problem directly anyway, because if the timer stops firing either Start or Enabled=True isnt called when it should be.

Comment: Iam using the Start at the init method, the Stop/Start in the event is to set the current count to 0(start over) becouse the event can be triggered by another callback to.

Comment: you might follow @CodesInChaos suggestion and at least post the (relevant part of) code inside the (tick) event handling method.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using the Start at the init method, the Stop/Start in the event is to set the current count to 0(start over) because the event can be triggered by another callback to.

That's likely your problem. Don't share a timer if you are using `Start`/`Stop`. You should probably use a queue instead which in turn is handled by a `BackgroundThread`.

Comment: Im not sharing timers? I use the same one the entire time. Pleas look at my updated post.

Comment: You said that different methods can start/stop it? That's sharing a timer.

Comment: So you say that I should not set the timer.Start() and timer.Stop() in my TimerEvent? That will be sharing timer? I dont really get it? What do you mean?

Comment: It sounded like different parts of the code could start and stop the timer. If so, one part might stop the timer while another would expect it to run.